# Key recovery when AES ECB is used for short but repeated messages

Tags: aes, attack, protocol-analysis, ecb

My question is based on [the specification of the protocol LoRaWAN](https://www.lora-alliance.org/portals/0/specs/LoRaWAN%20Specification%201R0.pdf) and especially on the part **6.2.5 Join-accept message**.

It is said that the join-accept message is encrypted using AES ECB. This is (normally) a single message created like that:

```
aes128_decrypt(AppKey, AppNonce | NetID | DevAddr | RFU | RxDelay | CFList | MIC)
```

Imagine that an attacker can listen the communications. He doesn't know `AppKey` (obviously), `AppNonce` and of course the `MIC`. If the attacker can make the end device send plenty join-request messages and if the server always responds with a corresponding join-accept message, can the attacker gain knowledge of the `AppKey` using the flaws in AES ECB?

**Disclaimer**: sorry if I'm not clear, cryptography is not my speciality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ECB mode has several weaknesses as discussed in [Why shouldn't I use ECB encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption) but in this specific case, it does not allow to gain information about the secret key `AppKey` involved.

Indeed, encrypting the same block with the same `AppKey` will returns the same ciphertext. But in the LoRaWAN join-accept message, it does not matter because the server encrypts **only one** 16-byte block which is `AppNonce | NetID | DevAddr | RFU | RxDelay | CFList | MIC`.

Plus, each such block should be different because as specified in the LoRaWAN specification :

1. > The AppNonce is a random value or some form of unique ID provided by
   >   the network server
2. > The DevAddr consists of 32 bits identifies  the  end-device within 
   >   the  current network

> If the attacker can make the end device send plenty join-request
>   messages and if the server always responds with a corresponding
>   join-accept message, can the attacker gain knowledge of the AppKey
>   using the flaws in AES ECB?

Note that a join-request has the following structure : `AppEUI | DevEUI | DevNonce` where `AppEUI` identifies the application and `DevEUI` identifies the end-device. So if an attacker make the end-device send plenty join-request messages, the server should remember that the device identified by `DevEUI` made a join-request a few time ago and should respond with the same `DevAddr` (or not respond at all) to avoid denial-of-services attacks. But I did not see anything about it in the specification.

Answer (score 5):

> If the attacker can make the end device send plenty join-request messages and if the server always responds with a corresponding join-accept message, can the attacker gain knowledge of the AppKey using the flaws in AES ECB?

No. ECB is flawed, but not that flawed.

At worst the attacker can know the encryption of a message if they have already seen the same message encrypted. (Or decrypted, as the case may be - LoRaWAN uses the decryption direction here to avoid having to implement both directions in the end-device.)

That can still lead to attacks, but key recovery is not possible.

Comment: Do you have any idea about what could be theses attacks?

Comment: @Shan-x, I don't think there's any attack *here*, just in general ECB is not semantically secure and easy to e.g. replay.

Comment: ECB is not **flawed**. You can't say that a brick is flawed because you can't live in it. ECB purpose is to build ciphers. It's operator flaw to use ECB in wrong way.

Comment: @Agent_L, ECB is a mode of operation, i.e. a way to *use* a cipher. I'm not aware of its use in building ciphers, what do you mean? While I grant that there are situations where using it is fine, as a general purpose mode for encrypting normal data it is very poor.

Comment: @otus well, ECB is as direct exposure of underlying AES as you can often get.